# Why does python return "NameError: name 'correct' is not defined when it has been defined?

Tags: python

Essentially I am making a quiz, and python returns an error saying the variable shown below is undefined when it has been defined.

```
def guesscheck(guess, answer):
    correct = "null"
    print(lives * '\u2665')
    if guess.upper() == answer:
        print("Marvelous! That is correct!")
        correct = True
        return correct 
    if guess.upper() != answer:
        print("That is incorrect.")
        correct = False
        return correct

lives = 3
guess = input("ok: ")
guesscheck(guess, "OK")
if correct == False:
    lives = lives - 1
    print(lives * '\u2665')
```

As you can see, I call the function which should define the variable 'correct' as True or False and return it to the rest of the program, but for some reason it is showing as undefined. Please help me!

Comment: hard to tell since you haven't formatted the code, but seems that the issue is that `correct` is in local scope to the function, try adding `global correct` at the top of function definition

Comment: It's only defined within the body of the `guesscheck` function. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: @Mattiiss I will try that.

Comment: Even if so, where are you using a loop in your code?

Comment: @JustANoobProgrammer, Yes the `return <variable>` statement does return something, but neither the name of a variable, nor a value, but a reference. And in order to use the reference you have to assign it to a variable of your own as the many answers suggest.

Comment: "My understanding was that if there is a variable was in a loop, the return function would return the value for the rest of the program to use." Yes. It will return the *value*. *Not* the name. There *isn't necessarily any name*. You can just as easily `return True` directly.

Comment: See also for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882728/python-variable-scope, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636867/how-can-i-share-a-variable-between-functions-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364313/why-does-my-function-not-return-value-to-global-variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the `correct` variable from your function and *then* access it when calling `guesscheck`:

```
def guesscheck(guess, answer):
    # This variable declaration is not necessary
    # correct = "null"
    #
    # Instead, you can assign it to the answer check
    correct = guess.upper() == answer

    print(lives * '\u2665')

    if correct:
        print("Marvelous! That is correct!")

    # You can use an else-clause here
    else:
        print("That is incorrect.")

    return correct
```

Then access it like this:

```py
lives = 3
guess = input("ok: ")
correct = guesscheck(guess, "OK")
# No need for `correct == False`
if not correct:
    lives = lives - 1
    print(lives * '\u2665')
```

Comment: Is "if not correct:" essentially a rewritten version of "correct == False:"?

Comment: Actually, `not correct` [also checks for additional things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39984051/9997212), such as empty strings and empty lists, while `correct == False` strictly checks for the boolean value `False`, but since `guesscheck` only returns a boolean, in your case they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below (note how correct is used in the main loop)

```
def guesscheck(guess, answer):
    correct = "null"
    print(lives * '\u2665')
    if guess.upper() == answer:
        print("Marvelous! That is correct!")
        correct = True
        return correct 
    if guess.upper() != answer:
        print("That is incorrect.")
        correct = False
        return correct

lives = 3
while lives:
    guess = input("ok: ")
    correct = guesscheck(guess, "OK")
    if not correct:
        lives = lives - 1
        print(lives * '\u2665')
```

Comment: Thank you, however, the code keeps running forever, and I need it to stop at some point so that I can put more than one question into the quiz code.

Comment: @JustANoobProgrammer I can see no reason for making `correct` global - isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

You do not define `correct` outside of the function, it is only available on the local scope.

Assigning on the outside scope should fix your problem.

```
correct = guesscheck(guess, "OK")
```